# Use tag 'value property in Angular attribute and event call parameters

Tags: javascript, angular

Beginner Angular/Javascript question...

In the code example shown below I have a 'value' set to '0'. In the two binding calls for "[checked]" and "(change)" I am setting the method calls to '0'.

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="view1" name="taskView" [checked]="isCurrentView(0)" mdbInput value="0" (change)="changeTaskView(0)">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="view1">Day</label>
</div>
```

Is it possible to replace the '0' used in the "[checked]" and "(change)" with the tag 'value' property?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) (`#var`) for this.

Use the hash symbol (`#`) to declare a reference variable. The following reference variable, `#taskview`, declares a `taskview` variable on an `<input>` element.

```
<input type="radio" #taskview ...>
```

Now you can refer to a template reference variable anywhere in the component's template. Here, `taskview` refers to the input element and we can pass its `value` to an event handler or attribute like:

```
<input type="radio" #taskview 
   [checked]="isCurrentView(taskview.value)"
   (change)="changeTaskView(taskview.value)">
```

Comment: I've noticed that 'taskview.value' is a string value. In terms of type checking ,  how can I convert this to a number within the code example you gave above?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. All solutions can be found [How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can provide `$event.target.value` to the functions.

```
<input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="view1" name="taskView" mdbInput value="0"
  [checked]="isCurrentView($event.target.value)"  
  (change)="changeTaskView($event.target.value)"
>
```